# Using reduce to check for even/odd numbers- code fails for odd num

Tags: javascript, reduce

The function ev call the reduce function insight it and is suppose to return true if an even number is in the array(which I pass to the ev function) and false if the array has an odd number. My code works for even numbers, but fails for odd numbers (shows true still) and I don't know why! Someone knows why?

```
var even = function(num) {
    return num % 2 === 0;
};

function reduce(array, init, func) {
    var curr = init;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        curr = func(curr, array[i]);
    }
    return curr;
}

function ev(arr, func) {
    if (arr.length > 0) {
        if (reduce(arr, 0, func)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true; //thats i the array is empty
}
ev([0, 11, 28], even);
```

Comment: Your question is unreadable.

Comment: I just realized that reduce is adding the numbers together and then checks for true, false I think.. how can I use the reduce function (I have to use it for purpose of an exercise) but not add them but check each number individually?

Comment: how is it not readable?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are supposed to use the built-in `map`/`reduce` functions in Javascript?

```
function isEven(val) {return !(val % 2)}

function or(a, b) {return a || b}

function containsEven(arr) 
{
    return arr.map(isEven).reduce(or)
}
```

**Edit 1:**

Or, even better, you can use the properties of even/odd multiplication to just check to make sure the product of the elements of the array is even:

```
function mult(a, b) { return a * b }

function containsEven(arr)
{
    return !(arr.reduce(mult) % 2)
}
```

**Edit 2:**

Now that it is clear that we want to check if all elements in the array are even, we would have the following code:

```
function isEven(val)
{
    // Equivalent to val % 2 === 0
    return !(val % 2)
}

function and(a, b) {return a && b}

// Checks to see if all elements in arr pass the checkFn
function ev(array, checkFn)
{
    return array.map(checkFn).reduce(and)
}

//can now call ev([0, 11, 28], isEven)
```

Comment: the point here is that I need to check odd/even FOR EACH element separate but still use the reduce function

Comment: Then my first solution should meet your requirements.

Comment: hmm I must call the ev function with both arguments like ev([0, 11, 28], even); Im not sure how to do that, if I use your solution :/

Comment: Thanks. I tried it but it still doesn't work-I still get true for odd numbers

Comment: Ok so we need to revisit your goal here. You say that it should return true if there is an even number and false if there is an odd number. These conditions only work if the list contains all odds or all evens, it would be self-contradicting for lists containing both evens and odds.

Comment: What were the exact words used in the problem statement?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112452/discussion-between-evan058-and-learningcoding).

Comment: it should return true ONLY if all numbers are even. If the list includes even just one odd number, it should return false. I actually changed my previous code and set initial value to true(0 was wrong). But now the problem is it checks every number setting the initial/current to true/false etc. That means if the last number is even it will give me true, even if all the other numbers before were odd.

Comment: Ahh, so it is an all even check. All I need to do is change my function from or to and

Comment: I don't quite understand your solution and it gives me an error when i run it

Comment: yea you're right, tried it again and it works!Thank you!! Can you explain whats happening there?We iterate (map) through the array, call the isEven function of each element. Then we call the reduce function with and function? don't quite understand. Also, how would it work if I changed the isEven function to {return (val % 2)} instead of function {return !(val % 2)} (The isEven function was already provided and I am not suppose to change it and it was without the "!"

Comment: So the map operation maps each element to a boolean indicating if that element is even or not. So after that operation we have an array of booleans. Then the reduce function basically "ands" every element together, like so: `[a, b, c].reduce(and)` `=>` `and(a, and(b, c))`. Since the `&&` operation is commutative, it is equivalent to `a && b && c`. This will only evaluate to true if every element is true.

Comment: Read more about the `reduce` operation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: so if after the operation we have an array of booleans, does the reduce(and) add the booleans together?!

Comment: No, it "ands" all of the elements together. `[a, b, c].reduce(and)` is equivalent to `a && (b && c)`

Comment: okay thank you for taking the time!! The only problem now is that I can't change the pre write isEven function and you changed it to checking for not !) even numbers

Comment: Like I have written in the comment in that function, it is 100% equivalent and always outputs the same thing. Don't use my version, it is interchangeable with your original `isEven`

Comment: I tried to remove the ! and then it stopped working and returned 0

Comment: Use your original function, it you want to understand what happened with your change, read about booleans in js

Comment: i did understand it eventually but that code still doesn't work if you put (val % 2) ao i don't understand what you mean by it doesn't matter

Comment: sorry, i had some other mistake thats why i would get 0. It all works now. thank you

Comment: Great! Please accept the answer if it has been helpful